# Permission denied in jnlp trying call showDocument with a pdf file

Tags: pdf, permissions, applet, jnlp

I need some help with this showDocument in my jnlp aplication.
I trying to show a pdf file in another tab from browser, but the java plugin denied.

My JNLP file has a

```
  <security>
        <all-permissions/>
  </security>
```

and my code is:

```
    AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction()
    {
        @Override
        public Object run()
        {
            try
            {
                applet.getAppletContext().showDocument(new URL("file:///C:/Contrato.PDF"), "_blank");
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                showException("Erro ao exibir arquivo:" + e.getMessage());
            }
            return null;
        }
    });
```

but I receive the exception

```
    java.lang.SecurityException: showDocument url permission denied
```

If I try to do showDocument(google.com, _blank) that works...but when I try to show any file, it does not work.

Comment: `showDocument(new URL("file:///C:/Contrato.PDF"), "_blank");` - `showDocument` was *not* designed for showing files off the computer of the end user!  Is this PDF on the client or the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `showDocument(URL)` method of `AppletContext` was never intended for launching files off the local file-system (even when specified as a `file` protocol URL).

There are at least two alternatives:

1. The JNLP snippet indicates this is a trusted app., so for a 1.6+ app., [`Desktop.browse(URI)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#browse%28java.net.URI%29) can be invoked.
2. The `BasicService` of the JNLP API offers the [`showDocument(URL)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/BasicService.html#showDocument%28java.net.URL%29) method.

Comment: You're welcome.  +1 for posting code that made the problem clear.